# What's the adjective for "not likely to have a boyfriend/girlfriend"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What's the adjective for "not likely to have a boyfriend/girlfriend"? As in "You're such a klutz; you won't get a boyfriend." or "You're always procrastinating; no girl would ever likes you." So what are "you" then?

Comment: There are any number of reasons why someone might be unlikely to attract a potential mate. There's the "generic" attribute [**unmarriageable**,](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unmarriageable) but even that doesn't automatically include people who can't even attract ***suitors***.

Comment: There is only one adjective in the English language for this. However, no one currently living has any idea what it is. It is expected that in about 10 years someone 10 years old will know what this adjective is. Wait 10 years, and you might find out what it is. Or you might find out that you no longer need it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

How about *unattractive*?

M-W:

> [*unattractive*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unattractive):
>   not beautiful, interesting, or pleasing : not attractive

One can be attractive or *unattractive* to another for any number of reasons, just not a good match.

Comment: Well, if you're unattractive, you're just not likely to get someone in bed with you rather than to get someone go steady with you.

Comment: This is a deceptively good answer. Unfortunately I suspect the masses will not perceive  it so.  But maybe if one thinks about the phrase, “he’s got many attractive qualities” and in this case “he’s got no attractive qualities”